# Castle Windsor, hook continer release in order to call explicit components release

Tags: castle-windsor, facilities

I run this at the application Start Up

```
public class ConfigurationFacility : AbstractFacility {
    private readonly List<string> configuredComponents = new List<string>();

    protected override void Init() {
        Kernel.ComponentRegistered += OnComponentRegistered;
        // add environment configurators
    }
    private void OnComponentRegistered(string key, IHandler handler) {
        // if the component is a configurator then run conf settings and add it to configuredComponents
    }}
```

Question: How to hook tear down and to call explicit release for each ?

Thanks

Comment: I hoped that overriding the dispose will help but it's not so :(

Comment: please explain a bit more: what do you call "tear down", what do you want to release and why.

Comment: At the application start up I'm doing environment validation and if something is not configured like external hardware connectivity ... I do it ... when the container (application) is stopped I'd like to uninitailze and do cleanup ... I know there are other ways to do this but I'd like something clean and simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either the `ComponentDestroyed` event of `IKernel` or just implement `IDisposable` in your components. Here's a little sample code:

```
namespace WindsorInitConfig {
    [TestFixture]
    public class ConfigurationFacilityTests {
        [Test]
        public void tt() {
            OneDisposableComponent component = null;
            using (var container = new WindsorContainer()) {
                container.AddFacility<ConfigurationFacility>();
                container.AddComponent<OneDisposableComponent>();
                component = container.Resolve<OneDisposableComponent>();
            }
            Assert.IsTrue(component.Disposed);
            Assert.Contains(component, ConfigurationFacility.DestroyedComponents);
        }

        public class OneDisposableComponent : IDisposable {
            public bool Disposed { get; private set; }

            public void Dispose() {
                Disposed = true;
            }
        }

        public class ConfigurationFacility : AbstractFacility {
            private readonly List<string> configuredComponents = new List<string>();
            public static readonly ArrayList DestroyedComponents = new ArrayList();

            protected override void Init() {
                Kernel.ComponentRegistered += OnComponentRegistered;
                Kernel.ComponentDestroyed += Kernel_ComponentDestroyed;
                // add environment configurators
            }

            private void Kernel_ComponentDestroyed(ComponentModel model, object instance) {
                DestroyedComponents.Add(instance);
                // uninitialization, cleanup
            }

            private void OnComponentRegistered(string key, IHandler handler) {
                // if the component is a configurator then run conf settings and add it to configuredComponents
                configuredComponents.Add(key);}
        }
    }
}
```

The static ArrayList is only for demo purposes, of course.